# Add ToggleButton to ArrayList of Buttons

Tags: android

I have a list of Button objects that I use to enable/disable all buttons at once. I use the following very simple code:

```
void buttonsEnabled(boolean enabled)
{
    for(Button btn : buttonList)
    {
        btn.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add a ToggleButton into the ArrayList `buttonList`, since it inherits from `CompoundButton` which inherits from `Button`, or is my thinking mixed up?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
           ↳    android.widget.Button
               ↳    android.widget.CompoundButton
                   ↳    android.widget.ToggleButton
```

If your ArrayList is an ArrayList of [`Button`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html), you can put a [`ToggleButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact thing I checked before trying. It didn't work as expected (the button was not enabled) so I thought I'd ask. I may have just found out why, though.

Comment: If you need more help, post the code where you create ArrayList, and where you add togglebuttons/buttons